# Implementing Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: convergence, measure-theory

[image]

I have to solve this limit using the Dominated Convergence theorem ( https://www.math3ma.com/blog/dominated-convergence-theorem ).

I'm not sure what to do with that "n" before the integral.
What would the g function look like? Thank you!!!

Comment: What does sh mean here?

Comment: The hyperbolic sine.

Comment: This might be a better candidate for the maths SE site unless you can highlight the statistical content?